# Как найти None в списке и заменить его?

Tags: python

Допустим, у меня есть список:

```py
example = ['1', '2', None]
```

Как мне найти в нем `None` и заменить на `'None'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
exаmple = [('None' if x is None else x) for x in exаmple]
```

Comment: Хех, код то ошибку вызывает

Comment: При правильно применении не вызывает. Это для того, чтобы подумать, а не бездумно скопипастить.

Comment: оно не берет данные со списка где только None

Comment: круглые скобки можно убрать

Comment: Я на всякий случай оставил, не хотел проверять как отработает. редко такие конструкции использую

Answer (score 3):

1. Взять элемент.
2. Посмотртеть, не None ли он.
3. Если да, то заменить на "None".
4. Перейти к следующему элементу.
5. Повторять, пока список не закончится.

Comment: Но взять его то я не могу.
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: Все могут, а ты не можешь. Значит, неправильно берешь ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ PS. Текст ошибки без кода, который эту ошибку вызывает, абсолютно бесполезен.

Comment: `for i, n in enumerate(labels):
        if i == None:
            i[n] = 'None'`
а вот вам код, но все же, ошибка

Comment: в одном месте стоит ``i``, а в другом ``i[n]``...

Comment: потому-что тогда оно будет выводить не то, если бы было i = 'None' .
А с помощью n я заменяю по индексу

Comment: индексу чего? индекс-то к labels относится

Comment: Ага, берем по элементу, а заменяем по индексу... ``i`` это что? а ``i[n]`` это что? Неплохо бы перечитать главу о списках.

Answer (score 2):

Если в списке кроме `None` только строки, то можно ещё так:

```
example = list(map(str, example))
```

Answer (score 1):

Способов миллион разных. Если в списке нет пустых строк и нулей, то можно ещё так по приколу:

```
example = [x or 'None' for x in example]
```

Comment: Ещё список не должен содержать False. Иначе `[x or 'None' for x in  ['', 0, False, None] ]  >>> 
['None', 'None', 'None', 'None']`. Ну или всё-таки явно сравнивать с None :  `[x is None and 'None' or x for x in example]`.

Comment: @GrAnd Да. Ну, я тут чисто по приколу, скучно уже банальности писать